# Difference of Global and Window objects

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the JavaScript Global object and Window object.  I know in both, you don't have to declare the object to use the methods.

Comment: you do have to declare them to use them, it's just that they are automatically declared for you and Window.prototype, like all prototypes, makes modification instantly available to all instances.

Comment: Are you talking about browser JS? You can run JS on the server. No `window` there. And a browser doesn't have a `global`, I think.

Comment: there are several "Globals"; non-strict this, window, self, top, implicit publishing (non-var declaration), ({}).constructor.prototype, Window.prototype, Object.prototype, etc. Any addition on one of those will appear as a lexical names in all scopes. "use strict" greatly reduces but doesn't eliminate this madness.

Answer (score 1):

The `window` object encapsulates the global scope. Omitting `var` (or `let`) when declaring a variable will implicitly add that as a property to the global scope. It's unique in that sense since there is no equivalent to `window` when inside a different scope.

I'm going to [quote myself](http://new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2014/01/21/experiments-with-javascript-es6) on this one:

> [MDN's description of `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) states that the global scope is bound to the global object. This would suggest that declaring a variable (either with var at the top level, or without var inside a function) simply adds a new property to `window` (or an equivalent outside of the browser).

Try it out. Create a variable without using `var`, then look at the `window` object in your console. You'll see it in there. It's the equivalent of doing this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
 value: "bar",
 enumerable: true // see @dandavis' comment on iterating over implicit global vars
)}
```

This doesn't explain *why* that's the case. Just that `window` is unique in that everything is defined within it.

Comment: enumerable is false by default, but implicit globals are iterable under window.

Comment: i think 'Global' probably means more of a concept than a particular object. in nodejs, there is no "Global", like browser's "Window", but node's 'global' provides the rough equivalent and its global.constructor.prototype===Object.prototype, whereas window.constructor.prototype!==Object.prototype

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems to me that the so-called globals are defined under the window object.

Comment: Do you know which browsers are the exceptions? I'm curious now. I do occasionally attempt to access globals via the window object.

Comment: i think we can all guess which one, but it rhymes with "dry heave" and didn't support "real" js until it's ninth version.

Comment: Hehe gotcha. I tested this on a newer version of IE and it worked (phew). At least now they are following standards that everyone else is following.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript that is running in a browser, window is at the top of the scope chain. If you define a "global" variable, it is implied that it is under the window object.

For example:

```
// Global variable
var g = 0;

function foo(){
    window.g = 1

    // This will output '1'
    alert(g); 
}
```

Comment: food for thought: if "window is at the top of the scope chain", why does it inherit from Object.prototype and Window.prototype?